# webpage loading.. 加载 vs 载入​​​​​​​

Tags: usage, vocabulary, synonyms

What words should we use when we want to say "a webpage is loading"?

In Gmail, when I change my settings to simplified Chinese, Google says "正在加载".

However, when I change my settings to traditional Chinese, Google says "正在載入" (正在载入 in simplified Chinese).

What is the difference in nuance and usage between 加载 and 载入?

Which is a better term to use to describe "webpage loading"?

Answer (score 6):

Strictly speaking, the word formations between 加载 and 载入 are a little different; however, as Alex has said, both are acceptable in your case.

> 加载(verb) = 加(verb, add) + 载(verb, load)
>
> 载入(verb) = 载(verb, load) + 入(preposition, in/into)

**EDIT**

Notice: both 加载 and 载入 can be used as a transitive verb or an intransitive verb.

In most cases, they are interchangeable; **however**, because 入 in 载入 has implied a preposition, if they are used just before a prepositional phrase, they act in different ways. For example:

> These data should be loaded into the cache.
>
> - 这些 数据 应当 **加载 到** 缓冲。
> - 这些 数据 应当 **载入 (到)** 缓冲。

As 载入 has implied 入(in), the preposition 到(to) can be omitted. In contrast, if you omit 到 in the first sentence, the sentence

> [Warning! May be ambiguous.] 这些数据应当加载缓冲。

is (most likely) considered as

> These data should load the (contents of the) cache.

So, as you see in this `加载/载入+prepositional phrase` case, they are **not equivalent**.

Comment: This is only different statements in different regions in this certain question.

Comment: @halfelf sorry, but I don't quite understand your sentence :) Did you mean my explanation was too localized and specific? I was to cover some minor aspects :P

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. I mean `加载` is often used in Mainland, while `载入` in Taiwan, HK and other places. There's no need to distinguish them here.

Comment: @halfelf In Baidu news search in simplified Chinese, 载入 has 1.8 million entries, and 加载 has 0.97 million entries. I can't conclude that your statement is true. And there're some idioms that can only use one of them, e.g. 载入史册 is correct but 加载到史册 is very wrong. Understanding the distinction is necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Simplified Chinese is usually used in Mainland China, and traditional Chinese is used in Hong Kong, Macau and Taiwan(and sometimes in other Cantonese-speaking areas). So the choice of words reflects the regional language habits. They may vary greatly.

But in this specific case, 加载 and 载入 are both acceptable. 加载 may sound a tiny little bit more (insert here an adjective that's related to jargon, terms, geek and stuff - I can't find one even in Chinese), but the difference is really trivial and you never have to worry about that.

Comment: @Pacerier In another word, no one will question your Chinese proficiency based on whether you use 加载 or 载入 in the context of computer software.

Comment: @NS.X. :) please check my post. The main difference between 载入 and 加载, is that 载入 has already implied a preposition.

Answer (score 1):

I want to write more, but they have the same meaning.

Ok more here: as one who works in Internet business for quite some time, we use it interchangeably.

Language-wise, although 入 sounds to need a word behind it as the place into/onto which the content is loading, it is often ommitted because in the context people knows where the content is loading into/onto.

Answer (score 1):

As a native speaker, I would remind you that try not to bother youself with so many details. Because as far as I am concerned, there is little difference between the two words, and both are accepted by most people. And some sites, trying to show their efforts to internationalize themeselves, even simply put a "loading..." on their pages. It's OK.

Chinese sometimes is a language for you to understand the meaning of it, rather than a logical language like English with clear structure and grammar.

Finally, to solve your problem, I would suggest "正在加载" or "网页载入中" or "loading..." according to my experience. Notice that there is no subject in "正在加载", therefore is can be reguarded as the translation of "loading". While in "网页载入中", the subject is “网页”, therefore the verb “载入” can give the users a kind of expectation that the page is "coming" and you'll be willing to wait.

Comment: Wait ... Chinese has clear structure and grammar, too. You can probably rely on the language intuition as a native Chinese speaker, and that's no problem with you; however, non-native speakers don't have such sense and if they don't follow some grammar rules, they would very possibly make mistakes. 我們中國人有時候忽略語法太多，反而有一種“不識廬山真面目，只緣身在此山中”的感覺了 :)

Comment: I second to @Stan that your comments are perfectly valid to other (pedantic) native speakers, but may not be a good advice for language learners. Differentiating synonyms is a key part in learning any language.

Answer (score 1):

Either "加载" and "载入" is acceptable translate for "loading" in the specific reference to transferring the content from a server to your computer.

Personally, I like "網頁加载中" better for "webpage loading" because its sounding.

The distinction between Traditional Chinese and Simplyfied Chinese is mainly the structure of the word, not necessarily the phraseology of terms (which of course can be very different in different parts of the Chinese speaking communities around the world).

For "webpage loading", it's 網頁加载中 in simplified Chinese, and 網頁加載中 in traditional Chinese.

It's unfortunate that Google uses different wording for the same message in its 2 versions of Chinese pages. Of course, no one should look to Google as the authority of Chinese language.

Comment: I think an answer would better be as impersonal as possible. And, it's not clear that which phrase the preferred "網頁加載中" is compared with, "網頁載入中" or "網頁正在加載"? OP's question is about the comparison between 加載 and 載入. If you were to suggest that "...中" would be more concise than "正在...", please state that point in detail, or, others might misunderstand you. BTW, in simplified Chinese, it should be "网页".